# Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\NewMessage::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\User, null given

Tags: laravel

Я делаю уведомления на laravel и у меня возникает подобная ошибка.

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\NewMessage::__construct() must be an instance of App\Models\User, null given, called in C:\Users\pavel1988\Desktop\open_server_5_3_7_basic_full\OpenServer\domains\test\test\app\Http\Controllers\NotificationController.php on line 31
```

Вот мой контроллер:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use App\Models\Message;
 use App\models\User;
 use App\Notifications\NewMessage;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Notification;

 class NotificationController extends Controller
 {
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->middleware('auth');
     }
  
     public function index()
     {
         // user 2 sends a message to user 1
         $message = new Message;
         $message->setAttribute('from', 2);
         $message->setAttribute('to', 1);
         $message->setAttribute('message', 'Demo message from user 2 to user 1.');
         $message->save();
          
         $fromUser = User::find(2);
         $toUser = User::find(1);
          
         // send notification using the "user" model, when the user receives new message
         $toUser->notify(new NewMessage($fromUser));
          
         // send notification using the "Notification" facade
         Notification::send($toUser, new NewMessage($fromUser));
     }
 }
```

А это модель User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Буду признателен любой помощи.

Comment: Ошибка говорит что вместо пользователя вы передаете пустоту. Проверьте что у вас в `$fromUser`, похоже что у вас нету пользователя с `id=2`

Comment: Cпасибо, помогло. Но теперь следующая ошибка:   Connection could not be established with host mailhog :stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.